# Entity Data Model works in Forms Application but not Class Library

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I began creating a VB.Net Class Library Project, and cannot get the edmx connection to work.  I can add edmx connections to other project types with no problem at all.  I am sort of new at creating class libraries, and VB.Net, more accustomed to MVC C#.

I've tried suggestions in other posts, making sure connection is in app.config, to no avail.

When instantiating myEntities, I get the error:

```
No connection string named 'myEntities' could be found in the application config file.
```

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim context As New MyEntities()
    Dim query = From items In context.mytable Order By items.ID Select items

End Sub
```

Although I'm not sure it's needed, here is the connection in app.config

```
<connectionStrings><add name="myEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myDBSERVER;initial catalog=myTable;persist security info=True;user id=myuserid;password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings></configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Class Library DLL doesn't read the app.config. You'll need to provide the connection string in code either by hard coding it, passing it in from the calling process or reading it from a config file in code.